# Unity: How to apply rotation on object's velocity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making top-down shooter on Unity and I need to implement shotgun, which will release 5 rounds at a time, each next will have rotation 10 degrees less than previous (from 20 to -20 in total). Instantiating the bullet on firepoint, the velocity is applied to it by bullet script, attached to bullet prefab. I apply the rotation in instantiating method too, but the bullet just rotates around itself, not to direction it flying.
Shooting code:

```
Vector2 mouseScreenPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
Vector2 direction = (mouseScreenPosition - (Vector2) transform.position).normalized;
transform.up = direction;

GameObject newBullet1 = Instantiate(bullet, firePoint.position, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 20f)) as GameObject;
newBullet1.GetComponent<Bullet>().direction = direction;
GameObject newBullet2 = Instantiate(bullet, firePoint.position, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 10f)) as GameObject;
newBullet2.GetComponent<Bullet>().direction = direction;
```

Bullet code:

```
public Vector3 direction;
public float bulletSpeed;

void Update () {
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector3 (direction.x, direction.y, transform.position.z) * bulletSpeed;
}
```

Comment: I think because you're adding velocity it will always move along the coordinates that increase. Have you tried [Rigidbody2D.AddForce()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html)?

Comment: Totally forgot to mention this in the question, sorry. The AddForce accelerates the object, not just moves. I do not need acceleration, because it is unrealistic with bullet.

Comment: You should instead be changing the 'direction' component of each bullet. The first bullet has the initial velocity vector, you need to modify this velocity vector for each bullet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the rotation to the direction vector for each bullet. Formula for the rotation of a vector is...
x1 = x0*cos(angle) - y0*sin(angle);
y1 = x0*sin(angle) + y0*cos(angle);

```
    Vector2 direction10 = new Vector2(direction.x*Mathf.cos(10*Mathf.Deg2Rad) - direction.y*Mathf.sin(10*Mathf.Deg2Rad), direction.x*Mathf.sin(10*Mathf.Deg2Rad) + direction.y*Mathf.cos(10*Mathf.Deg2Rad));
    Vector2 direction20 = new Vector2(direction.x*Mathf.cos(20*Mathf.Deg2Rad) - direction.y*Mathf.sin(20*Mathf.Deg2Rad), direction.x*Mathf.sin(20*Mathf.Deg2Rad) + direction.y*Mathf.cos(20*Mathf.Deg2Rad));

    newBullet2.GetComponent<Bullet>().direction = direction10;
    newBullet3.GetComponent<Bullet>().direction = direction20;
    ... //etc
```

Can probably do this cleaner with a loop.

Comment: It partially worked, but works only if my character are facing x or -x axis. If it faces y of -y, 2 bullets fly directly towards y, and 2 towards -y, remaining one flies towards random x, all with almost or no spread.

Comment: may have mixed up my formulas a bit... try the new one

Comment: Now it works properly only is character faces the positive x or y axis. If negative, only one bullet flies towards right direction, others is flying the opposite. Tried many ways to change operators in the formulas, but that had no effect.